# While using View Pager inside View Pager , not showing item of child view pager

Tags: android, android-fragments, navigation, android-viewpager

In my application parent view pager have 5 fragments and 2 of them using second view pager inside it which contain another 5 fragments. For navigation In Parent view pager, I am using Bottom navigation. and In child for navigation, I am using Tab layout.

Problem is All View except the view of child view pager is showing inside parent viewpager.https://ibb.co/2ScB3N6

I notice that if the child view pager's item showing after reach the last item. for example, if I reach the last item then if I go to the 2nd item then it's showing.https://ibb.co/jLdT9Zf

Also if I change item(which have view pager inside it) position to first then when stared at that time only i's showing it's item but when I change item of parent view pager to second then go to first then same problem occur.

**Code of Parent view pager Adapter:**

```
public class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
    private final List<Fragment> mFragmentList = new ArrayList<>();

    public ViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager manager) {
        super(manager);
    }
    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        return mFragmentList.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mFragmentList.size();
    }

    public void addFragment(Fragment fragment) {
        mFragmentList.add(fragment);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemPosition(Object object) {
        // POSITION_NONE makes it possible to reload the PagerAdapter
        return POSITION_NONE;
    }
}
```

**All method related to Parent viewpager Initialization:**

//************--Setup view Pager--*********************
calling BottomNavigationmethod() and viewPagerMethod() into onCreate

```
   private void setupViewPager(ViewPager viewPager) {
        ViewPagerAdapter adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
        home=new Home();
        home.setArguments(HomeBundle);
        speed=new Speed();
        speed.setArguments(HomeBundle);
        rpm=new Rpm();
        rpm.setArguments(HomeBundle);
        spdRpm=new SpdRpm();
        spdRpm.setArguments(HomeBundle);
        dataRecord=new DataRecord();

        adapter.addFragment(home);
        adapter.addFragment(rpm);
        adapter.addFragment(dataRecord);
        adapter.addFragment(spdRpm);
        adapter.addFragment(speed);
        viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
```

//***************--Botton navigation method--***********

```
    public void BottomNavigationmethod(){
        bottomNavigationView.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(
                new BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
                    @Override
                    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
                        switch (item.getItemId()) {
                            case R.id.action_home:
                                viewPager.setCurrentItem(0);

                                break;

                            case R.id.action_rpm:
                                viewPager.setCurrentItem(1);


                                break;
                            case R.id.action_dataRecord:
                                viewPager.setCurrentItem(2);


                                break;
                            case R.id.action_spdRpm:
                                viewPager.setCurrentItem(3);


                                break;
                            case R.id.action_speed:
                                viewPager.setCurrentItem(4);
                                break;

                        }
                        return false;
                    }
                });
    }
```

//****************-- view Pager method--******

```
  public void viewPagerMethod(){

        GetCurrentItem=String.valueOf(viewPager.getCurrentItem());

        Log.d("getcurrntinside",GetCurrentItem);
        viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {

            }


            @Override
            public void onPageSelected(int position) {
//                viewPager.getAdapter().notifyDataSetChanged();
                if (prevMenuItem != null) {
                    prevMenuItem.setChecked(false);
                }
                else
                {
                    bottomNavigationView.getMenu().getItem(0).setChecked(true);
                }    
                Position=String.valueOf(position);
                bottomNavigationView.getMenu().getItem(position).setChecked(true);
                prevMenuItem = bottomNavigationView.getMenu().getItem(position);

                OnViewPager=String.valueOf(bottomNavigationView.getMenu().getItem(position));


            }

            @Override
            public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {

            }
        });

        setupViewPager(viewPager);
    }
```

**Menu xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_home"
        android:checked="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/cartab"
        android:title="@string/HomeTab"
        app:showAsAction="always" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_rpm"
        android:checked="false"
        android:icon="@drawable/rpmtab"
        android:title="@string/RpmTab"
        app:showAsAction="always" />


    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_dataRecord"
        android:checked="false"
        android:icon="@drawable/rpmtab"
        android:title="@string/DataRecordTab"
        app:showAsAction="ifRoom" />

    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_spdRpm"
        android:checked="false"
        android:icon="@drawable/spdrpmtab"
        android:title="@string/SpeedRpmTab"
        app:showAsAction="ifRoom" />

    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_speed"
        android:checked="false"
        android:icon="@drawable/speedtab"
        android:title="@string/SpeedTab"
        app:showAsAction="always" />

</menu>
```

**View pager adapter of child view pager:**

```
public class ViewpageAdapterFrg extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
    public List<Fragment> fragmentList=new ArrayList<>();
    public List<String> fragmentTittle=new ArrayList<>();


    public ViewpageAdapterFrg(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        return fragmentList.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return fragmentTittle.size();
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        return fragmentTittle.get(position);
    }

    public void fragmentAdd(Fragment fragment, String text){
       fragmentList.add(fragment);
       fragmentTittle.add(text);
    }
    @Override
    public int getItemPosition(Object object) {
        // POSITION_NONE makes it possible to reload the PagerAdapter
        return POSITION_NONE;
    }
}
```

**Method related to child view pager:**
calling this method into on create

```
public void apptabview(){
    tabLayout=(TabLayout)view.findViewById(R.id.tabs);
    viewPager=(ViewPager)view.findViewById(R.id.viewpage);

    ViewpageAdapterFrg FirstAdapter=new ViewpageAdapterFrg(getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager());

    FirstAdapter.fragmentAdd(new NormalRpmFragment(),"Normal");
    FirstAdapter.fragmentAdd(new AwesomeRpmFragment(),"Awesome");
    FirstAdapter.fragmentAdd(new PointerRpmFragment(),"Pointer");
    FirstAdapter.fragmentAdd(new ProgressRpmFragment(),"Pointer");
    FirstAdapter.fragmentAdd(new DeluxeRpmFragment(),"Deluxe");

    viewPager.setAdapter(FirstAdapter);

    Log.d("speedViewFragemnt",String.valueOf(viewPager.getCurrentItem()));
    tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
}
```

I tried viewpager.getAdapter.notifyDatasetChanges() inside various event of child view pager's addOnPagerListen but its freeze the app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 getChildFragmentManager()
```

Returns a private FragmentManager for placing and managing Fragments inside of a Fragment.

```
 getSupportFragmentManager()
```

Returns the FragmentManager for interacting with fragments associated with this fragment’s activity.

In your method related to child view pager

```
ViewpageAdapterFrg FirstAdapter=new ViewpageAdapterFrg(getChildFragmentManager());

FirstAdapter.fragmentAdd(new NormalRpmFragment(),"Normal");
FirstAdapter.fragmentAdd(new AwesomeRpmFragment(),"Awesome");
FirstAdapter.fragmentAdd(new PointerRpmFragment(),"Pointer");
FirstAdapter.fragmentAdd(new ProgressRpmFragment(),"Pointer");
FirstAdapter.fragmentAdd(new DeluxeRpmFragment(),"Deluxe");

viewPager.setAdapter(FirstAdapter);

Log.d("speedViewFragemnt",String.valueOf(viewPager.getCurrentItem()));
tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
```

Comment: getActivty() is required while using in fragment. other than that what different in your code

Comment: Your using view pager inside of a Fragment , so you need to use `getChildFragmentManager()`  instead of `getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager() `

Comment: Try with `ViewpageAdapterFrg FirstAdapter=new ViewpageAdapterFrg(this.getChildFragmentManager()); `  in case `getChildFragmentManager() `  cannot be resolved or referenced

Comment: Unlikely  getSupportFragmentManager() , getChildFragmentManager() doesn't even need context of it's fragment. so simply getChildFragmentManager() worked

Comment: Great it helped !!